# appication insights operation_id being changed

Tags: azure-application-insights

With applicaiton insights logging, I am trying to get the operation_id to be a guid that we use throuhgout the rest of the system.  I pull a row out of the database, which already has a correlationID, and I want to use this correlationID as the operation_id when I log to applicaiton insights.

I have the StartOperation method below:

```
internal static IOperationHolder<RequestTelemetry> StartOperation(TelemetryConfiguration configuraiton, string operationName, string correlationId)
{
    TelemetryConfiguration config = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
    config.ConnectionString = configuraiton.ConnectionString;
    CorrelatingTelemetryInitializer initializer = new CorrelatingTelemetryInitializer(correlationId);
    config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(initializer);
    TelemetryClient tc = new TelemetryClient(config);
    var operation = tc.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>(operationName);
    return operation;
}
```

This creates a new configuraiton, so I can add a custom initializer, and uses the exising connect string.  It added my custom initializer that takes the correlationID as a parameter.  Then I create a new TelemetryClient and start an operation from that.

I then use it like this:

```
using (var operation =  EventTelemetry.StartOperation(_telemetryConfiguration, "Publishing Event", domainEvent.CorrelationId.ToString()))
{
_logger.LogWarning($@"Testing with operaiton ID {operation.Telemetry.Context.Operation.Id}");
}
```

In my log message I am logging the operation id and I see that it is set to the guid.  However, the operation_id shown for applicaiton insights is different.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/28808fff-e1f9-4bf0-8d7e-c08ddf0d4844/requests-operation-id-changed-to-number?forum=ApplicationInsights)

Answer (score 0):

- set both RequestTelemetry.Id and Context.Operation.Id with the internal Id your application uses.

```
var client =  new  TelemetryClient();  
var request =  new  RequestTelemetry(/* request parameters */);
request.Id  = internalId; 
client.Context.Operation.Id  = internalId; 
// all telemetry tracked through this client will now be linked to the request client.Track(request);
```

- For further details check this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/28808fff-e1f9-4bf0-8d7e-c08ddf0d4844/requests-operation-id-changed-to-number?forum=ApplicationInsights)